# How to efficiently adjust the AMIX_MAG and BMIX_MAG parameter in VASP calculations?

Tags: vasp, software

I'm trying to calculate the magnetic anisotropy energy of  Cr<sub>2</sub>O<sub>3</sub> by comparing the total energy difference of the system in different spin configurations (in-plane and out-of-plane). However, when doing VASP scf calculations with Hubbard U settings, the calculation did not converge for 400+ electronic steps.

I read from the [vasp wiki](https://www.vasp.at/wiki/index.php/BMIX) that you can set the optimal `AMIX` by looking at the `GAMMA` value in OUTCAR:

> In VASP the eigenvalue spectrum of the charge dielectric matrix is calculated and written to the OUTCAR file at each electronic step. This allows a rather easy optimization of the mixing parameters, if required. Search in the OUTCAR file for
> eigenvalues of (default mixing * dielectric matrix)
> The parameters for the mixing are optimal if the mean eigenvalue Γmean=1, and if the width of the eigenvalue spectrum is minimal. For an initial linear mixing (BMIX≈0) an optimal setting for AMIX can be found easily by setting AMIXoptimal=AMIXcurrent*Γmean.

But my question is, **how to adjust the `AMIX_MAG` and `BMIX_MAG` parameters for magnetic system calculations?** Are there some guidelines on how to efficiently adjust them for optimal calculation speed?

Comment: I gave my +1 a long time ago but didn't have time to comment (the Autumn 2021 term was extremely busy for me!). I'm sorry to see that your bounty didn't lead to any answers! I see that you wrote "However, when doing VASP scf calculations with Hubbard U settings, the calculation did not converge for 400+ electronic steps" but didn't give any input or output file. Can you provide those in `code` blocks if they take up fewer than 30000 characters, or add them here otherwise (in a folder called 6905 since that's the number in this question's URL): https://github.com/HPQC-LABS/Modeling_Matters

Comment: I'll echo what @NikeDattani asks, the question does need more specificity about all the other parameters for the calculation. While the `AMIX`, `AMIX_MAG` and their B equivalents _do_ influence convergence, so do many other factors. For example, with magnetic systems in particular, such as the one here, the algorithm can matter; `ALGO = A` in my experience gets stuck at magnetic saddle points less than others. It may be that for this relaxation to converge well, the algorithm or something else needs to change.

Comment: This question appears to be abandoned, it can be reopened if the OP responds to suggestions in the comments.